# UI amberi not loading but wekan dashboard loaded when using virtualbox and hortonwork hdp

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hortonworks-sandbox

I am newbiw in hadoop env. I have installed virtual box and download hortonwrk sandbox hdp 2.6.5 to open ui amberi. The virtual vm show https://localhost:1080 and https://localhost:4200. When i open this link in broswerr, it hsow wekan dashboard. not ui amberi.

How to open ul amberi ? Need help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

First, Hortonworks Sandbox is no longer supported or maintained, so you should find another solution.

If you see a different service on either port, then you have something else running on your host or as a VM, and occupying those addresses, and it's not a Virtualbox/Hadoop/Ambari problem. Ambari is showing local addresses **within the VM**, not addresses for your host. You can edit the VM's port mappings to use some other host port.